# Axis web service deployment error and WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, axis

I have a legacy `SOAP` based web service built using `Axis framework`. When I try to deploy it in WebSphere, I get connection refused error and deployment fails, but I still can access the `WSDL` through the browser. Does that mean the `service` is up and running? I am using `Axis AdminClient` to deploy the service.

```
   AdminClient ac = new AdminClient();
   String result = ac.process(
                   new String[] {
                    "-p" + API_PORT,
                     "-l"+API_PROTOCOL+"://"+API_HOST+":"
                     + API_PORT
                      + "/mywebservice",
                       deploymentdescriptorfile });
```

How can the wsdl be accessible when deployment fails?

Comment: Websphere Liberty or "traditional" WebSphere?  Traditional has an axis2 impl built in that can interfere with other  impls.  More info at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=dws-using-third-party-jax-ws-web-services-engine

Comment: @BruceT. - its Websphere ND and the service engine is disabled. But the error getting is 'connection refused'. Seems like a firewall related issue. But my question is how the wsdl is accessible when the service is not deployed yet?

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but sometimes wsdl's are packaged as static web content in an app, maybe the deployment is getting that far.